# Automatic sequencing of records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table containing telephone numbers belonging to companies and individuals (customers). Each customer can have more than one telephone number, and they often want them listed in a particular order, so the table has a `sequence` field to sort each customer's telephone numbers according to their preference. The fields are:

- `parent_id` - char
- `sequence` - tinyint
- `area_code` - string
- `number` - string

The primary key is the combination of `parent_id` and `sequence`.

So far so good. The "problem" comes when I want to move a number up in the order, or delete a number.

When moving a number up, the way I do it (with PHP) is changing that record's `sequence` to 0 (a customer's first telephone number is normally 1, I use 0 just for this), then incrementing the preceding number's `sequence` by 1, and then setting the original record's `sequence` to 1 less than it was. In other words, swapping the `sequence` with the preceding telephone number, but it takes three queries.

When deleting a telephone number, I delete that record, and then I have to re-sort that customer's remaining telephone numbers so that there is no missing `sequence`. It depends on how many telephone numbers that customer has, but it can be several queries.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` can affect multiple records at once; for example:

1. Moving sequence #4 up to #2:

   ```
   UPDATE my_table SET sequence = CASE
     WHEN sequence = 4 THEN 2
     WHEN sequence < 4 AND sequence >= 2 THEN sequence + 1
   END WHERE parent_id = ? AND sequence BETWEEN 2 AND 4;
   ```
2. Deleting sequence #3

   ```
   DELETE FROM my_table WHERE parent_id = ? AND sequence = 3;

   UPDATE my_table
   SET    sequence = sequence - 1
   WHERE  parent_id = ? AND sequence > 3;
   ```

However, you should be very cautious about using `(parent_id, sequence)` as your PK if `sequence` is subject to change in this manner.  It may well be better to define a completely synthetic PK.

Comment: The delete example works great. It saves me from iterating through the records in PHP :) However, in the example for moving a sequence up,  MySQL returns a duplicate key error.

Comment: @ironcito: Ah, good point.. one would have to do two updates.  I'd do `WHEN sequence = 4 THEN NULL` in the update above, appending `ORDER BY sequence DESC` to the end; then a second update `SET sequence = 2 WHERE parent_id = ? AND sequence IS NULL`.  Of course, if `sequence` is in your PK then it can't be set to `NULL` so you would have to use a "magic" value (like the 0 that you're currently using) - but I'd see that as another argument for removing `sequence` from your PK.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this for deleting:

`DELETE FROM phone_numbers WHERE parent_id = '{$parentID}' AND sequence = '{$seq}'`

`UPDATE phone_numbers SET sequence = sequence + 1 WHERE parent_id = '{$parentID}' AND sequence < '{$seq}'`